# How to seamless animation loop using the Wave modifier

Tags: modifiers

How can I seamlessly animate this text object using the Wave modifier without making a jolt movement when it goes to frame 1 again?

[image]

Comment: Big fan of [McGlasham](https://www.youtube.com/@ianmcglasham) , myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At frame 1 keyframe the *Offset* value in order to get the shape you want:

[image]

At the end of the timeline, tweak the *Offset* until you get the shape as it should be just before it comes back to frame 1, keyframe again:

[image]

Comment: Very good, thank you!